# How to choose values for resize() value in Picasso

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-drawable, picasso

I have added an `Image View`, and set these values.

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@ivNewsHeader
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

I get images from server, and they are very high res images, if i add them as is, i end up getting `OutOfMemoryError`.

So i learnt that `picasso` offers a great way to tackle this. I used following, and this scale down any image which is higher than the mentioned dimensions.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL).
                                    resize(180, 130).
                                    onlyScaleDown()
                                    .into(ivNews);
```

Now when i choose these `resize(180, 130)`, the performance is very good and i don't get any `OutOfMemoryError`, but the image quality is very poor.

So my question is how to choose resize number, and what equation should is use to put correct `width-height` numbers in `resize() method` to get the perfect image without compromising the quality and performance.

My `imageView` height is `250dp` and width is `match_parent`

Answer (score 2):

Specify scale value based on device size

**Device width in pixel**

```
 public static int getScreenWidth() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }
```

**Convert DP to Pixel**

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

**Now use these two function**

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL).
                                    resize(getScreenWidth(), dpToPx(250)).
                                    onlyScaleDown()
                                    .into(ivNews);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `fit()` is what you need, because will crop your image to `ImageView` size on screen. In this case, you don't need do to any more calculations.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
       .load(imageURL)
       .fit()
       .centerInside()
       .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks @Florescu, Is centerInside() better in performance than centerCrop(), before i was using centerCrop(), and it was causing memory issue.

Comment: I think is the same, but you will have different results. You can check on next like for more details about scale type. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: With `Picasso` you can use `centerInside()` and `centerCroop`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fit()` which is measuring the dimensions of the target ImageView and internally uses resize() to reduce the image size to the dimensions of the ImageView.

Quoting from this [article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Comment: Thanks @dhamas, what if i use `centerCrop()`, is centerInside() better in performance then centerCrop()?

Comment: In centerInside(), the image will be displayed completely, but might not fill the entire ImageView but in centerCrop(), the ImageView will be filled completely, but the entire image might not be displayed